# Facebook Website Login

Tags: facebook, authentication, question2answer

I set up a website http://www.howpedia.de with the framework http://www.question2answer.org/ there is an integrated Facebook login that does not work for me or a fried of mine (so the error is not on my site).

If i click on signup with facebook, the popup for login shows up, asking for permission and closes itself again. But i am not logged in on my site. If i reclick on the login, the popup opens and closes itself with no error or what so ever.

Since i am using an already integrated facebook login plugin from the framework and the thing is working on the official Q&A Site http://www.question2answer.org/qa/ i have no clue what to do.

Steps so far:

1. Registered an facebook app
2. enabled login for my site howpedia.de and www.howpedia.de
3. copied public and private key into my website
4. facebook login was enabled, sandbox mode is off

I also tried to register another APP to try it with different public / private key, but the result is the same.